# Problem Mapping Objects with Tables

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I keep getting problem saving, I perfectly can read from database using hibernate. When I try to write to the database. It says nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:

```
[8/20/11 14:46:40:250 EDT] 0000017a event         E   Received 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException' when invoking action listener '#{enterpriseBean.savePersonService}' for component 'j_id5'
[8/20/11 14:46:40:250 EDT] 0000017a event         E   org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:737)
    at com.mycomapny.myproject.dao.impl.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:34)
    at com.mycomapny.myproject.service.impl.myprojectServiceImpl.createNewPerson(myprojectServiceImpl.java:41)
    at com.mycomapny.myproject.beans.EnterpriseBean.savePersonService(EnterpriseBean.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:99)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:774)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:372)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1152)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1485)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:531)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$16.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 57 more

[8/20/11 14:46:40:250 EDT] 0000017a AjaxViewRoot  E org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot processEvents Error processing faces event for the component j_id0:j_id5
                                 javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: /pages/PersonNew.xhtml @25,37 actionListener="#{enterpriseBean.savePersonService}": org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:118)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:774)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:372)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1152)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:764)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(HibernateTemplate.java:737)
    at com.mycomapny.myproject.dao.impl.BaseDaoImpl.createOrUpdate(BaseDaoImpl.java:34)
    at com.mycomapny.myproject.service.impl.myprojectServiceImpl.createNewPerson(myprojectServiceImpl.java:41)
    at com.mycomapny.myproject.beans.EnterpriseBean.savePersonService(EnterpriseBean.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:187)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:99)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: [Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person;
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1485)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.getEntityState(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:531)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$16.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 57 more
```

I think my spring beans are good. If you can take a look and tell me what is wrong

```
<beans      xmlns ="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd"
        >

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="theDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/myprojectdb"
        cache="true" resource-ref="true" lookup-on-startup="false"
        proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource" />

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="theDataSource" />

        <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
        <value>com/mycompany/myproject/domain/MailBox.hbm.xml</value>
        <value>com/mycompany/myproject/domain/Person.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction management -->

    <!-- Transaction Manager Hibernate -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

        <bean id="transactionAttributeSource" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.NameMatchTransactionAttributeSource">
        <property name="properties">
            <props>
                <prop key="save*">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"></property>
        <property name="transactionAttributeSource" ref="transactionAttributeSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionAdvisor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor">
        <property name="transactionInterceptor" ref="transactionInterceptor"></property>
    </bean> 

    <!-- Beans - DAO -->

    <bean id="mailboxDao" class="com.mycompany.myproject.dao.impl.MailboxDaoImpl">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="personDao" class="com.mycompany.myproject.dao.impl.PersonDaoImpl">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="hibernateTemplate" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Beans - Service facade -->
    <bean id="myprojectServiceFacade" class="com.mycompany.myproject.service.impl.myprojectServiceImpl">
        <property name="mailboxDao" ref="mailboxDao" />
        <property name="personDao" ref="personDao" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Beans - for views -->

    <bean id="mailboxBean" class="com.mycompany.myproject.beans.MailboxBean">
        <property name="myprojectService" ref="myprojectServiceFacade" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="enterpriseBean" class="com.mycompany.myproject.beans.EnterpriseBean">
        <property name="myprojectService" ref="myprojectServiceFacade" />
    </bean>

    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message, you seem to call `saveOrUpdate` with an array of entities as argument (`[Lcom.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person` means array of `com.mycomapny.myproject.domain.Person`). You can't do that. `saveOrUpdate` takes only one entity instance as argument. Not an array.

Side note: you might want to choose a better package name than `com.mycomapny.myproject`. At least spell `company` correctly.

Comment: Then show us the code you're using to save your entities, and which throws this exception.